# How to have multiple spinners with one set of code

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-relativelayout

All- I have a layout that looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to have those three spinners on all of the rows. Right now they are only on St. James (yes, this is Monopoly). Each spinner has a significant amount of code with it and to create a whole new spinner from scratch for each row is difficult at best. I tried to duplicate the first row and only change the text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/stjameslay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_james_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/st_james" 
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

      <Spinner android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"         
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_james_place" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/houses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/owner"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/hotels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/houses"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />   
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/balticavelay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/stjameslay">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_james_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/baltic" 
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

      <Spinner android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"         
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_james_place" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/houses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/owner"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/hotels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/houses"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />   
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/boardwalklay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/balticavelay">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_james_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/boardwalk" 
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

      <Spinner android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"         
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_james_place" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/houses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/owner"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/hotels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/houses"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />   
    </RelativeLayout>           
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see from the screenshot, the spinners did not show up. My thinking was that since the id was the same on the spinners, the Java code would just treat the extra spinners as duplicates. Is there a way to do this or am I going to have to make new spinners for each row and new Java code (owner2, houses2, hotels2, etc.)? Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you effectively need to do this as a `ListView`. Create a 'list item' layout file to represent a single list row, example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/propertyLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/propertyName"
        ... />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/owner"
        ... />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/houses"
        ... />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/hotels"
        ... />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

You then need to create a custom `Adapter` to map/bind the data to each widget and use that with the `ListView`.

Comment: Much more elegant than my suggestion.   +1.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question there: The second row spinners is referring to the id of the first row. All spinner id must be unique, if you wish to place them uniquely in the RelativeLayout, and if you wish to look them up in the activity code.

Define a new id for the second row textview from @+id/st_james_place to @+id/textBaltic, then the spinner next to it can now be changed to android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textBaltic" and android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textBaltic", then change the spinner's id to @+id/spinnerBalticOwner, the next spinner can refer to it like this: android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinnerBalticOwner".

Do this for all the current row spinners and the spinners in the next row and all your spinners should show up properly.

To initialize the spinners in a loop:

```
int[] spinnerIds = new int[] {R.id.owner, R.id.houses, R.id.hotels, R.id.owner2, R.id.houses2, R.id.hotels2, R.id.owner3, R.id.houses3, R.id.hotels3};

for (int i = 0; i < spinnerIds.length; i++) {
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerIds[i]);
   // standard spinner initialization code
   if (spinner.getTag().equals("owner")) {
     // init spinner based on owner spinner
   } else if (spinner.getTag().equals("houses")) 
     // init spinner based on houses spinner
   } else if (spinner.getTag().equals("hotels")) {
     // init spinner based on hotels spinner
  }
```

}

Then in your layout you need to add 'android:tag' to all your spinners, add tag='owner' to the first column spinners, tag='houses' to the second column, tag='hotels' to the third column:

```
  <Spinner android:id="@+id/owner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:tag="owner"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"         
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/st_james_place" 
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
 <Spinner android:id="@+id/houses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:tag="houses"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/owner"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />
 <Spinner android:id="@+id/hotels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:tag="hotels"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/houses"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/st_james_place" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

For this to work, all spinners id must be unique, my example just append the row number to the original id, e.g. R.id.owner (1st row), R.id.owner2 (2nd row), R.id.owner3 (3rd row).

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid because than I would have to write another set of Java code for spinnerBalticOwner.

Comment: just point them towards the same method. As far as im aware, they need seperate Ids.

Comment: There's no avoiding the need to create/init a spinner for each Spinner you have in the layout. How else are you going to differentiate the result of a spinner is from Boardwalk's 3rd spinner, as oppose to St. James Place's 1st spinner? However, you can use an array holding the spinner ids and 'android:tag' property to help you initialize the spinner in a loop, rather than doing it one by one.

Comment: Could you give me some sample code for the array with the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this, but theoretically, it should work.

I would break that spinner setup into a separate xml layout and then use `include` in the xml to add it to each parent (property) layout.

Then you can set the spinners by referencing them from their parent views even though they have the same id (much like how a list row works).

```
RelativeLayout boardwalk = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.boardwalklay);
Spinner boardwalkowner = (Spinner) boardwalk.findViewById(R.id.owner)
// set your spinner here
// do the same for the other two spinners
// repeat for each property
```

If each spinner is actually the same but for the parent, create a method to populate them and just call the method once you've got the reference to the particular spinner.

Then in the`onItemSelected`grab the reference to the parent and you can relate it to each separate space.

Comment: How would I use include in xml?

Comment: Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)